# Optimising the speed/time complexity/scalability of double/nested for-loops in Python 3: itertools, parallelise, multiprocessing, concurrent

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, for-loop, concurrency

I have two UK NHS healthcare datasets: df_oa containing 181,000 pairs of coordinates and df3 containing 8,000 pairs of coordinates.

The specification of the code is to append any areas (df_oa.code) within 3km of a doctor's surgery (df3.Organisation_Code) to construct a list (surgery_oa_list), along with the km distance measurement, to iteratively build a matrix. The order of outputs is not important. Non-parallelised run time is currently estimated at ~3-4 days on a 2.9 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i9 Processor with 32 GB 2400 MHz DDR4 RAM.

Having explored optimisation solutions, suggestions include:

- itertools (though for a brute-force operation my understanding is that this will not make a difference to time complextity)
- concurrent.futures
- multiprocessing.Pool

However in terms of optimal solution, including pool/thread calculations, I am unclear which solution is optimal and what order of speed bump could realistically be achieved. If you have experience in this area I would greatly appreciate your advice &/or code suggestions:

```
from geopy.distance import distance
surgery_oa_list = []
failed = []
outer = 0
for i in range(len(df3)):
    inner = 0
    results = 0
    processed = 0
    for j in range(len(oa_df)):
        try:
            d = distance((float(df3["Lat"][i]), float(df3["Lon"][i])), (float(oa_df["lat"][j]), float(oa_df["lon"][j]))).km
            processed += 1
            if d <= 3:
                surgery_oa_list.append([df3["Organisation_Code"][i], oa_df["code"][j], d])
                results += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print("failed :" + str([df3["Organisation_Code"][i], oa_df["code"][j]]))
            print("type error: " + str(e))
            failed.append([df3["Organisation_Code"][i], oa_df["code"][j], df3["Lat"][i], df3["Lon"][i], oa_df["lat"][j], oa_df["lon"][j]])
        if inner % 30000 == 0:
            print(str(outer) + ", " + str(inner))
        inner += 1
    print("hits: " + str(results))
    print("processed: " + str(processed))    
    outer += 1
print("done")
```

Comment: This sounds like you should use a spacial data structure that provides efficient lookup for nearby points, rather than trying to write a faster brute-force loop.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really helpful answer and I quickly wanted to acknowledge that I am now exploring GIS options (which seem excellent).

If you or anyone else has suggestions on how this might also be solved in a brute force loop, assuming that this were not spacial data (I acknowledge that in the case of spacial mapping, a spacial index seems optimal) - I think answers would be a useful addition to stackoverflow (as presently there is nothing comprehensive in this area).